# Predictive distribution derivation from Bishop "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning "

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I have a question regarding one part in section 4.5.2. Specifically conclusions about equation (4.148):

$$p(a)=\int \delta(a-\mathbf{w}^T\phi)q(\mathbf{w})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{w}.$$

I think context is not that important, the only relevant thing is that $a$ is projection of $w$ on $\phi$. So the puzzling part is this

> We can evaluate $p(a)$ by noting that the delta function imposes a linear constraint on $w$ and so forms a marginal distribution from the joint distribution $q(w)$ by integrating out all directions orthogonal to $\phi$.

I really do not see how linear constraint on $w$ imposes that all orthogonal directions to $\phi$ will be integrated out. Can someone elaborate?

Comment: In the theory of distributions, this integral is $\delta_S[q]$, where S is the hyperplane of $\mathbb R^M$ defined by $a-{\bf w}^T{\bf\phi}=0$ (a linear constraint imposed by delta function), which is further equal to $\int_Sq({\bf w})d{\bf w}$ (see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) -> Properties in n dimensions -> paragraph beginning with "More generally, ..."). The last integral is conducted on all $\bf w$ which are orthogonal to $\bf\phi$, which is just the definition of a marginal distribution along $\bf\phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lebesgue substitution theorem tells us that for any map $A : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ that is 'nice enough' (diffeomorphism) we have

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(A(x)) |\det \partial A(x)| dx$$

where $\partial A$ is the Jacobi matrix. For a linear map $A$ we have $\partial A(x) = M$ where $M$ is the representing matrix of $A$. Take a fixed nonzero vector $\phi_1 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and complete it to any orthonormal basis $\phi_1, \phi_2, ..., \phi_n$ (for example, using the Gram Schmidt algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process), i.e.
  $$\langle \phi_i, \phi_j \rangle = \mathbf{1}_{i=j}$$
i.e. is one iff. $i=j$ and zero otherwise.

Now we consider the function
  $$f(x) = \delta(a - x^T\phi_1) g(x)$$
for any other 'nice' (i.e. measurable so that the whole thing can still be integrated, your function is 'nice enough' :-)) function $g$. We consider the linear bijective map
  $$A : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n, ~~~ A(e_i) = \phi_1$$
where $e_i = (0, ..., 0, \underbrace{1}_{i-\text{th position}}, 0, ..., 0)^T$ is the reguar $i$-th standard vector. This matrix has the representing matrix $M$ where the vectors $\phi_1, ..., \phi_n$ w.r.t. the standard basis are the columns. Such a matrix must have determinant $\pm 1$: As the vectors are orthonormal to each other and $M^T*M$ contains the scalar product $\langle \phi_i, \phi_j \rangle$ as $i,j$-th entry,
  $$M^T*M=I$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. Hence, $\det(M)^2 = \det(M^T*M) = \det(I) = 1$.

Using the substitution above we get
  $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(A(x)) |\det \partial A(x)| dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(A(x)) |\pm 1| dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(A(x)) dx$$

Now what happens when we write $A(x)$ into $f$? First of all we realize that 
  $$x^T\phi_1 = \langle x, \phi_1 \rangle$$
and then also
  $$A(x) = A(x_1, ..., x_n) = x_1\phi_1 + ... x_n \phi_n$$
so that
  $$A(x)^T \phi_1 = \langle x_1\phi_1 + ... x_n \phi_n, \phi_1 \rangle$$
but since all the $\phi_j$ are orthogonal to $\phi_1$ except for $\phi_1$ itself, we get
  $$A(x)^T \phi_1 = \langle x_1\phi_1 + ... x_n \phi_n, \phi_1 \rangle = x_1$$
and consequently
\begin{align*}
  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(A(x)) dx 
    &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \delta(a-x_1) g(x_1\phi_1 + ... + x_n \phi_n)dx\\
    &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} ... \int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta(a-x_1) g(x_1\phi_1 + ... + x_n \phi_n) dx_1 dx_2 ... dx_n \\
\end{align*}

Now here comes a catch: The author of the book you are referring to seems to think that
  $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbf{1}_{x_1 = a} \text{somefunction}(x_1) dx_1 = \text{somefunction}(a)$$

which is a physicians 'naive' view on the world (because a formal integral over a function that is zero almost everywhere is certainly zero!). So, repeated once again:

*** FORMALLY, THIS IS NONSENSE, IT IS WRONG!!! ***

Nevertheless, if interpreted correctly, this could work (not absolutely sure about this point though). Usually, people do not take the 'hard' delta function $\mathbf{1}_{a=w^T\phi}$ but some 'soft' kernel that allows values other than $a=w^T\phi$ but only close ones and the 'close' gets closer within a limit or so. In any case: If you want to do it formally correctly, then it is more complicated.

Nevertheless, if we follow the 'wrong' way above then we obtain
\begin{align*}
  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(A(x)) dx 
    &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \delta(a-x_1) g(x_1\phi_1 + ... + x_n \phi_n)dx\\
    &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} ... \int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta(a-x_1) g(x_1\phi_1 + ... + x_n \phi_n) dx_1 dx_2 ... dx_n \\
    &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} ... \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(a\phi_1 + ... + x_n \phi_n) dx_2 ... dx_n
\end{align*}

you see: We take the function $g$ and integrate out all directions $\phi_2, \phi_3, ..., \phi_n$ that are orthogonal to $\phi_1$.

Comment: Thank you, good sir, I think I follow the logic, have to think it through again tomorrow. Few comments though.
1. M∗M=I . I assume you meant M transpose as first operand, right?
2. Main thing is that this delta function is Dirac delta function and is not equal to 1 in 0, but to infinity, but it is integrated to 1. So I guess it is exactly function you described in the last paragraph after warning, right?

Comment: @Andre: 1) M^T: yes you are right, I will correct. 2) delta: There is no function whatsoever that takes a value different from 0 only at one single point and integrates to something unequal to zero. Even the function taking the value "infinity" at this single point integrates to zero. What phisics people mean is the 'evaluate at a single point'-distribution, not an integral (caution: not probability distribution but in the differential equation sense!). Anyhow, this is a nonsense, philosophical discussion that should not take place here :-)